# Colocar trecho entre parenteses

Tags: php

Tenho este código:

```
if(isset($params['bedrooms']) && is_numeric($params['bedrooms']) && $params['bedrooms'] > 0){
    $what['bedrooms >= ?']  = $params['bedrooms'];
    $what_or['suites >= ?'] = $params['bedrooms'];
 }

 $where = implode(' AND ',array_keys($what));
 $conditions = array_values($what);
 if (!empty($what_or)) {
   $where .= ' OR ' . implode(' OR ', array_keys($what_or));
   $conditions = array_merge($conditions, array_values($what_or));
 }
 pr($where);
 die();
```

Que vai me resultar em:

`modality_id = ? AND property_type_id = ? AND properties.city_id = ? AND status = ? AND bedrooms >= ? OR suites >= ?`

Porém preciso retornar isto com **`bedrooms >= ? OR suites >= ?`** entre parenteses, como posso fazer isso?

Ps: sem usar **str_replace()**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque a condição do `bedrooms` na sua array de `OR`:

```
$what_or['bedrooms >= ?']  = $params['bedrooms'];
$what_or['suites >= ?'] = $params['bedrooms'];
```

Depois ajuste a parte que monta o SQL assim:

```
if (!empty($what_or)) {
   $where .= ' AND (' . implode(' OR ', array_keys($what_or)) . ')';
   $conditions = array_merge($conditions, array_values($what_or));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Assim obtive como resultado isto : `modality_id = ? AND property_type_id = ? AND properties.city_id = ? AND status = ? AND garage >= ? AND bedrooms >= ? OR (suites >= ?)` quando preciso que me resulte assim `modality_id = ? AND property_type_id = ? AND properties.city_id = ? AND status = ? AND garage >= ? AND (bedrooms >= ? OR suites >= ?)
`

Comment: Atualizei a resposta @GWER, veja se resolveu.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito Obrigado!